# Put two divs both sides of the center

Tags: html, css

I want to put two divs both sides from the center.

```
<div class="wrap">
   <div class="left"></div>
   <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Sorry about links, can't upload images because of low raiting.

I want this:

[image: Example]

Not this(if i'm using "`text-align: center`"):

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add an additional div for the align:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="inner">blah</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="inner">blah blah blah blah blahblahblahblah blah blah</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

then in CSS

```
.wrap {
    display:block;
}
.left, .right {
    display:inline-block;
    width:49.5%;
}
.left {
    text-align:right
}
.right {
    text-align:left
}
.inner {
    background:#ccc;
    padding:20px;
    width:auto;
    display:inline
}
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n1jc6dwL/1/)

Comment: Good answer! I think this is exactly what the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you can divide the main wrapper in two parts then float the divs on each side

like

```
<div class="wrap">
 <div class="half_div">
   <div class="left"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="half_div">
   <div class="right"></div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

css as:

```
.half_div{
 width:50%;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using position relative and absolute for left and right divs:

```
.wrap {position: relative;}
.wrap > div {position: absolute;}
.wrap .left {
    right: 50%;
    ...
}
.wrap .right {
    left: 50%;
    ...
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/epoe0uct/1/

The idea is to set left div's `right: 50%` and right div's `left: 50%`.